# CentOS stops right after selecting kernel when installing CentOS on VirtualBox using Vagrant and Windows 11 Host OS

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7, vagrant, windows-11

I have the following setup:

- Host OS: Windows 11 Enterprise Versio10.0.2 2000 Build 22000
- Vagrant version 2.2.19
- Oracle virtualbox version 6.1.32

If I try to start a CentOS 7 VM config like:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "generic/centos7"
end
```

And:

```
vagrant up
```

VirtualBox/CentOS VM stops immediately after kernel is selected (boot loader menu) with a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner.

If I use e.g. Ubuntu or SUSE 11, VirtualBox VM starts just fine.

In the fail situation the last entries in VBox.log file is:

```
00:00:07.653694 GIM: KVM: VCPU  0: Enabled system-time struct. at 0x000000007ff78000 - u32TscScale=0xe7e226e8 i8TscShift=-1 uVersion=2 fFlags=0x1 uTsc=0x29a64f7a2 uVirtNanoTS=0x12dcee6ef TscKHz=2208006
00:00:07.653721 TM: Host/VM is not suitable for using TSC mode 'RealTscOffset', request to change TSC mode ignored
00:00:07.794451 GIM: KVM: Enabled wall-clock struct. at 0x000000007ffc8000 - u32Sec=1645464903 u32Nano=829866400 uVersion=2
00:00:07.946757 PIT: mode=2 count=0x4a9 (1193) - 1000.15 Hz (ch=0)
```

And nothing more is logged until I power off the VM in the VirtualBox GUI.

Any Idea's why centos does not want to start?

PS: Microsoft Hyper V stuff is disabled. And since other guest OS'es works I assume Hyper V is properly disabled.

Edit 22.02.2022: I found out that if VM is limited to one CPU it actually starts up, so this issue seems to be related to virtualbox not being able to grab more than one CPU on windows 11. Why?

Perhaps it is related to [enter link description here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=105315) and https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=105315

Comment: I've had issues with an install, that appeared to be a faulty install medium. Have you installed from this particular medium before?

Comment: Install medium? Everything is downloaded from respective sources, vagrant from vagrant, virtualbox from virtualbox.org and CentOS-7 box from vagrant. I have used this CentOS box just fine on windows 10, but after windows 11 upgrade CentOS do not want to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: A downgrade of VirtualBox to version 6.1.30 fixes the issue. So there is a bug in VirtualBox 6.1.32.